# Empty database taking 200 Mb

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio

I created a C# project in Visual Studio and used a database, before sending the project I deleted everything from my database and only kept the tables, but the database is taking about 150,000 kb. Why is this happening?

[image: Folder]

Comment: When data are deleted from a table, database log grows.

Answer (score 0):

because you have tables in that database and tables are structures that reserves disk spaces.
also database files have a default minimum size which will increase when they are filled by data (there is a setting for that)

but also you can shrink your database file size, if there is free space in the file after:

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (database_name)
```

see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkdatabase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for more information